# How to apply Photoshop like Filters to canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs, camanjs

I've a psd and I want to apply the filters set in that pdf to a canvas.
I'm using CamanJS library for that.

But the issue is range is different in Photoshop and Canvas. I tried to convert it but I'm not getting the same result as Photoshop.

Any idea if there's any conversion tool for that.

For example, Hue has range of 0 to 360 in Photoshop. Whereas in Canvas it is 0 to 100.

I'm open to using any other library if that can make this task easier.

[image: Required Filters]

Here's my Input image.

[image]

And here's what I want to achieve.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can experiment with CamanJS Filter adjustments, but here's my attempt at the effect you want:

```
curves: 'rgb', [0, 0], [100, 50], [150, 200], [255, 255]
vibrance: 5
saturation: -40
colorize: '#cc9922', 35
contrast: 10
gamma: 1.3
```